# Exact search on model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a search input and I wish to query my Tag table for exact matches in the string. For example...

## Tags

- Hat
- Jacket
- Shoes

`$query = "red and black shoes";`

`Tag::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->get();`

The above search is what I've been trying but gives no results. I would like `shoes` to be returned.

A row should only be returned if its an exact match for all or part of the user's query.

Comment: which db you using?

Comment: mariadb - thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `whereIn` method like this:

```php
$query = "red and black shoes";
Tag::whereIn('title', explode(" ", $query))->get();
```

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#where-clauses) for more info.

**Update**: If you have multiple words tags, you may use this (not tested):

```php
$query = "red and black shoes";
Tag::where(function($q) use ($query) {
    foreach (explode(" ", $query) as $item) {
        $q->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', "%$item%");
    }
})->get();
```

**Update 2:** If you want exact search, you have to explode your query by 2 words, 3 words etc. and use `orWhereIn` method in chain:

```php
$query = "red and black shoes";
Tag::where(function($q) use ($query) {
    $wordCount = str_word_count($query);

    for ($x = 1; $x <= $wordCount; $x++) {
        $q->orWhereIn('title', magicExplode(" ", $query, $x));
    }
})->get();
```

The `magicExplode` is a custom function that splits the given string by number of words, for example:

```php
magicExplode(" ", "red and black shoes", 1);
// ['red', 'and', 'black', 'shoes']

magicExplode(" ", "red and black shoes", 2);
// ['red and', 'and black', 'black shoes']

magicExplode(" ", "red and black shoes", 3);
// ['red and black', 'and black shoes']

magicExplode(" ", "red and black shoes", 4);
// ['red and black shoes']
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't seem to work for tags that have multiple worded tags like "star wars".

Comment: @panthro then you can't search like that. How you explode Hat
Jacket
Shoes?

Comment: @panthro updated my answer, check if it works please.

Comment: Thank you, it's not what im looking for though, it now does not return exact matches.

Comment: @panthro so you have to explode your query by 2 words, 3 words etc. and use `orWhereIn` method in chain. I updated my answer